# How can I make variable number of variables in java?

Tags: java, variables

I am new to Java can anyone help me to find a way to make variable number of variables during Runtime. (e.g.: I am designing a program to solve equations of any degree in that case I don't Know how many varriables I need.)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Read about Java collections, or maybe arrays.  This is the general way to deal with your problem.  You could also look into maps, if you need a way to name each "variable."

Answer (score 0):

if you know the no.of variables you will need in run-time then `Array` else
You can use a construct called `varargs` to pass an arbitrary number of values to a method. You use `varargs` when you don't know how many of a particular type of argument will be passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ArrayList` to store the variables ,and pass to the method,or any other structure can store variables